# How can I reduce margins in example lists?

Tags: margins

[image]

Is it possible to reduce the margin between the alphabetical indexes and the sentences but still keep them vertically aligned?

Comment: `exe` and `xlist` are not standard commands and you have given no indication of their definition. Do not show code as an image show a small complete document as text that shows the problem